# Numpy array within a specific range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

I have a numpy array, `z`, of around 400,000 values. The range of `z` is from `0 to 2.9`

I want to divide this array into four parts:

```
z1 = 0.0<z<=0.5
z2 = 0.5<z<=1.0
z3 = 1.0<z<=1.5
z4 = 1.5<z<=2.9
```

I have been using:

```
z1 = np.where(np.logical_and(z>0, z<=0.5))
z2 = np.where(np.logical_and(z>0.5, z<=1.0))
```

the above does not seem to give me `z1` or `z2` within the required range (approximately `z1` should be an array of length 100,000 with values in the range `0<z<=0.5`!! **I have tried it with simple arrays of length 100 or so and it works.**

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there another way of dividing my array into four parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `np.where()` returns the indices. To get the values you can do:

```
z1 = np.take(z, np.where(np.logical_and(z>0, z<=0.5))[0])
```

and so forth...

It is perhaps faster to directly use the mask to obtain the values through fancy indexing:

```
z1 = z[np.logical_and(z>0, z<=0.5)]
```

Comment: in your examples you have used `z1` inside the boolean expressions. I only have `z` and `z1` has not yet been defined.

Comment: it is still giving me the entire `z` and not the values within the range

Comment: @Srivatsan for me both the solutions with `np.take()` or fancy indexing... I am creating `z` as `z = np.linspace(0, 2.9 ,1000)`

Comment: I don't know why it did not work before, but when I sorted my array `z = np.sort(z)` it worked